# Asp.net MVC5 with Angular 2 configuration

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, angular-http

I'm beginner in Angular 2. I'm creating Angular project using Angular CLI. I'm separately creating asp.net MVC Web api project.

- Using angular CLI to `ng serve` command start this service: `localhost:4200`
- MVC web api start this service: `localhost:65320`

When i use Angular http **get** request to download data from `localhost:65320/api/myservice`, Cross origin problem occurred. Because angular project using different url. But i'm adding header to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*` problem solved.

But when i use http **post** request always return `405 method not allowed` problem occurred

Question:

- How to allow cross origin **post** request in web api controller?
- Or how to configure Angular CLI created project work together with MVC project?

**Correct Answer:**

Web api cross origin problem solved following this article:
https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors suggest by @chandermani

Comment: Have you looked at this msdn article https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: @Chandermani no. i will see. tnx

Comment: @Chandermani Thank you. Your link solve my Cross Origin request `POST` problem .

Comment: Great! post your fixes as an answer, so it can be marked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable CORS in Web API in two different ways:

1. Using Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors: follow tutorial https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api as [Chandermani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/361151/chandermani) pointed out.
2. Add the following to your system.webServer element in your web.config:

   `<httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>`

Comment: I'm trying your option 2. But POST request always return `405 method Not allowed`. Now i'm solving problem using `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` library

Comment: In some scenarios of the [CORS Specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) the client sends a Preflighted Request to the server using the OPTIONS method, which you probably did not implement, hence the 405 method not allowed. This is automatically implemented by Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors, but was not available in older versions of MVC.